# I get a token error when creating k3s cluster (2nd node)

Tags: rancher, k3s

when creating a HA k3s cluster, the first master node goes well, but the second node fails with this error "starting kubernetes: preparing server: bootstrap data already found and encrypted with different token"

I install it like this:
`curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - server --node-taint CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoExecute --tls-san 10.0.0.200`

when I run the above I got a message like this:
[INFO]  systemd: Starting k3s
Job for k3s.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status k3s.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

then when I run `journalctl -xe`  I can see my hint:

"starting kubernetes: preparing server: bootstrap data already found and encrypted with different token"

Answer (score 2):

I found the help in the comments [here](https://ukposts.info/have/high-availability-k3s-kubernetes-in-minutes/jZ-Al4KPnZdppok.html) , it turns out that I need to copy the token from the first node, and use it when I create the 2nd (and 3rd) node like this

1. on the first node:
   `cat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/token`
2. on second node: first cleanup the old failed installation:
   `/usr/local/bin/k3s-uninstall.sh`
3. re-install with token like this:
   `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - server --node-taint CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoExecute --tls-san 10.0.0.200 --token K1BBBBBBBBBaa549016::server:f98BBBBBBBBBBBBBa86bbea260`
   (token is actually different and longer and my IPs are actually a bit different)